# How do I write into a writable stream conditionally only if it is open?

Tags: node.js

I have this function in my module which writes to a `child process's` `stdin` stream. But sometimes I face

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:800:14)
```

I think its happening because sometimes the writable stdin stream is closed before I write into it. Basically I want to check whether its closed or not. If its open I'll write into it otherwise I won't write into it.

**Relevant Code**

```
/**
 * Write the stdin into the child process
 * @param proc Child process refrence
 * @param stdin stdin string
 */
export function writeToStdin(proc: ChildProcess, stdin: string) {
    if (stdin) {
        proc.stdin.write(stdin + '\r\n');
        proc.stdin.end();
    }
}
```

Is there an API to check it as I couldn't find any?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`finished`](http://devdocs.io/node/stream#stream_stream_finished_stream_callback) api from streams

```
const { finished } = require('stream');

const rs = fs.createReadStream('archive.tar');

finished(rs, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Stream failed', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Stream is done reading');
  }
});

rs.resume(); // drain the stream
```

Comment: I want to check a writable stream whether its open or not. If its open I will write stuff into it otherwise I won't write into it.

Answer (score 0):

nodejs documentation references the field `writable` on `WritableStream` objects, which seems to be what you're looking for: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#writablewritable

```
Is true if it is safe to call writable.write(), which means the stream has not been destroyed, errored or ended.
```